# Telerik Error Creating Control

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I tried Telerik Q2 2013 Trial and then decided to go back to Telerik Q1 2013 which is working ok but I have projects which when I open the old controls shows like this:

```
ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.2.717.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Any idea on how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Kim

Comment: possible duplicate of [why Rad Controls Design is not visible at design time in my solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132520/why-rad-controls-design-is-not-visible-at-design-time-in-my-solution)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving the [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) a try. From the site:

> The Assembly Binding Log Viewer displays details for assembly binds.
>   This information helps you diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot
>   locate an assembly at run time. These failures are usually the result
>   of an assembly deployed to the wrong location, a native image that is
>   no longer valid, or a mismatch in version numbers or cultures. The
>   common language runtime's failure to locate an assembly typically
>   shows up as a TypeLoadException in your application.

When you uninstalled the trial version, the assembly references in your web.config were probably not updated to the version numbers you currently have. Make sure the version number of your referenced DLL matches the web.config entry. i.e. Expand your references folder in your project and check the 'Version' property. You can also try removing and re-adding the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following KB regarding this issue:

[Design-time Troubleshooting](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/design-time-troubleshooting.html)